# Variable expanding in a script shell

Tags: shell, ssh

My code is:

```
nb_lignes=`wc -l $1 | cut -d " " -f1`
for i in $(seq $(($nb_lignes - 1)) )
do
machine=`head $1 -n $i | tail -1`
machine1=`head $1 -n $nb_lignes | tail -1`
ssh root@$machine -x " scp /home/file.txt root@$machine1:/home && rm -r /home/file.txt"
done
```

Is $machine1 taken as a variable or a string? If a string, how can I change it — by adding a quote?

Comment: Learn to use `sh -x script` (and how to interpret its output), so you can see the answer for yourself.  You'll see what the shell is executing, and would know that it was expanding the `$machine1` in the `ssh` command.

Comment: You can prevent `wc` from printing the filename by using stdin: `nb_lignes=$(wc -l < "$1")`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Instead of `head -n $n | tail -n 1` you could use: `sed -ne ${n}p` which is more efficient and clean...

Comment: @F.Hauri: If you're going to get into dissecting and rebuilding the script, there are many, many changes to be made, including that one.  The loop recalculates `machine1` on each iteration, but gets the same result each time, for example, plus the code uses back ticks instead of `$(…)`, and …

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Of course, things have to be re-thinked... Using `tac` for sample of `mapfile` under [tag:bash]. Have a look at my rewrited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$machine` will expand to `head $1 -n $i | tail -1` result, `$machine1` will expand to `head $1 -n $nb_lignes | tail -1` result.

You could figured it out by yourself.

Btw, `ssh root@` …

Comment: ssh  root@$machine -x " scp /home/file.txt root@$machine1:/home && rm -r /home/file.txt"   Here $machine1 will expand to head $1 -n $nb_lignes | tail -1 result ?

Comment: Yes, it $machine1 will expand to the result of the 'head | tail' command.

Answer (score 1):

`$machine1` will be expanded to give the value of variable `machine1`, because you are using double quotes`"`.  If you had used single quotes `'` then it would not have been expanded.

One possible confusion is when you embed a variable inside other text.  In this case you are fine, because the trailing character is a `:` (`root@$machine1:/home`) which is not a valid character in a Bash variable name.  Some shells (csh) would not have liked that, if you are not sure then you can delimit the variable name using `{ }`, for example:

```
root@${machine1}:/home
```